# Complex Analysis: Proof that if a function is zero on a sequence with a limit, then it's identically zero.

Tags: complex-analysis

I've seen it stated somewhere that the following theorem is a corollary of Cauchy's integral formula, perhaps also within the realm of Laurent series:

> If $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic on a domain $D$ and if $z_n$ is a sequence such that $z_n\in D$ and $z_n\rightarrow z\in D$ and $f(z_n)=0$ then it follows that $f$ is identically zero.

However, I can't seem to find a proof (that is simple enough that I can read) which demonstrates the claim.  I know the proof of the Liouville theorem, which seems somewhat similar and lies roughly in the same territory as this theorem, but I don't see how the proof could be adapted to this case.

Comment: Use the existence of this sequence to show that there is a sequence of points $w_n \to z$ for which $f'(w_n) = 0$. Use this to conclude that $0 = f(z) = f'(z) = ...$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $f$ is not identically $0$. Let $m$ be the order of $z$ as a zero of $f$. Then $f(w)=(w-z)^mg(w)\,,\ w\in D,$ for some analytic function $g$ on $D$ that satisfies $g(z)\neq0$. In particular $g$ is continuous so there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$
|g(w)-g(z)|<\frac{|g(z)|}2
$$
for $w$ in $\mathbb{D}(z,\delta)$. Notice that this implies $g$ doesn't vanish in $\mathbb{D}(z,\delta)$. Hence $f$ doesn't vanish in $\mathbb{D}(z,\delta)\setminus\{z\}$, a contradiction since $z_n\to z$.